# Some opportunities to get a better education exist

Tags: word-order, infinitives, syntax

My English teachers said that changing the position of an infinitive may not change anything.

Example,

- Some opportunities to get a better education exist.
- Some opportunities exist to get a better education.

They said: "None of them is wrong grammatically and they go to the same meaning but their emphasises are slightly different." What do you think?

Comment: They are right. Neither is wrong and both mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: Well, does it mean that "to get a better education" in the second sentence functions as an adverbial? I think it must be an adverbial.

In that case, can we relocate in the beginning?

To get a better education, some opportunities exist. @Lambie